# $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{(x^2+2x)}-\sqrt{(x^2-2x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have no idea how to attack and solve this problem. The solutions manual shows the answer is $-2$, but how do I get there?

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{(x^2+2x)}-\sqrt{(x^2-2x)}$$

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please see [this advice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\sqrt A-\sqrt B=\frac{A-B}{\sqrt A+\sqrt B}$

Answer (score 2):

Do the substitution $x=-1/t$, which transforms the limit into
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1-2t}-\sqrt{1+2t}}{t}
$$
which should be easier (it's a derivative).

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{(x^2+2x)}-\sqrt{(x^2-2x)}$$ can be written as 
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{(x^2+2x)-(x^2-2x)}{\sqrt{(x^2+2x)}+\sqrt{(x^2-2x)}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{4x}{\sqrt{(x^2+2x)}+\sqrt{(x^2-2x)}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{4x}{x(\sqrt{1+\frac 2x}+\sqrt{1-\frac 2x})}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{4}{(\sqrt{1+\frac 2x}+\sqrt{1-\frac 2x})}$$
Use the fact that $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}(\frac nx)=0$$

Comment: It is a little bit beyond a good hint in my opinion.

Comment: More importantly, $$\sqrt{x^2\pm2x}\ne x\sqrt{1\pm2/x}$$

Comment: Ok, but how can I know that the answer is -2 and not 2?